# Laravel 4 cannot drop foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to drop Foreign key on a table, but I got this message:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'user_id  
  '; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table `posts` drop foreign key   
  user_id)
```

And I am using migration to do this:

```
Schema::table('posts', function($table) {
            $table->dropForeign('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

I am sure that the 'user_id' exists in the 'posts' table:

```
 Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
```

How can I fix this? Is it a bug or something?

------------------
update:
I found that the reason might be that "you are trying to delete a key which is being used by another table."
Does that means I should drop those tables that uses 'posts' table first?

Comment: Did you previously assigned the `foreign key`, is this still a foreign key in your database table ?

Comment: @WereWolf - The Alpha I assigned 'user_id' as the foreign key for the 'posts' table, and I have 'comments' table that uses 'id' from 'posts' as foreign key. Maybe I should dropForeign key from bottom up - drop foreign key from 'comments' first, then 'posts'??

Comment: Is that if I have tables that depend on 'posts' table(pivot table), I can't drop the foreign key from 'posts'???

Comment: Your foreign key is probably named `posts_user_id_foreign`, not `user_id`.

Comment: @Marwelln you are right!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When creating a foreign key, the name will be `table_fields_foreign` unless you set a name in the second parameter ([see `createIndexName` method)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L730).

So if you didn't specify a name your foreign key should be `posts_user_id_foreign` and not `user_id`.

Comment: please elaborate your answer with the solution, it looks more like a suggestion. I am still unable to get what to do to update foreign key by your method. @Marwelln